# Snowflake Copy Into - Multiple column escape handling

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a unique situation while loading data from a csv file into Snowflake.

I have multiple columns that need some re-work

1. Column enclosed in "  and contains columns - this is handled properly
2. Columns that are enclosed in " but also contain " within the data i.e. ( "\"DataValue\"")

My File Format is as such:

```
    ALTER FILE FORMAT DB.SCHEMA.FF_CSV_TEST 
    SET COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
    FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' 
    SKIP_HEADER = 1 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
    TRIM_SPACE = FALSE 
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE 
    ESCAPE = NONE
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE' 
    DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
    NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

My columns enclosed in " that contain commas are being handled fine.  However the remaining columns that resemble ( "\"DataValue\"") are returning errors:

Found character 'V' instead of field delimiter ','

Are there there any ways to handle this?

I have attempted using a select against the stage itself:

```
    select t.$1, t.$2, t.$3, t.$4, t.$5, TRIM(t.$6,'"')
    from @STAGE_TEST/file.csv.gz t
    LIMIT 1000;
```

with t.$5 being the column enclosed with " and containing commas
  and t.$6 being the ( "\"DataValue\"")

Are there any other options than developing python (or other) code that strips out this before processing into Snowflake?

Comment: Have you tried adding the \ as an escape character?  It looks like your quote values are properly escaped, so that should take care of those quotes.

Comment: Mike That worked!! Thank you so much!!  How do I give you a thumbs up, or something equivalent?

Comment: I'll place it down as an answer, since it worked for you!  Feel free to upvote and accept the answer.  Glad it was something easy for you to fix!

Comment: Me too, thank you again.  I accepted, and tried to upvote, but I don't have enough creds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the \ to your escape parameter. It looks like your quote values are properly escaped, so that should take care of those quotes.